# My statistic parameters estimations in Python are taking too many time. How do I optmizate my code to run it faster?

Tags: python, optimization, parameters, statistics, estimation

I know that Python isn't the fastest language for speed, but I was trying estimate parameters and simulate to calculate statistics, but this take a lot of time. Is any way of optimazating this code to make it faster on Python? With 100 repetitions it took me 25 minutes and I want to make 10000.

```
from numpy import log, array, random, append
from scipy.stats import expon, kurtosis, skew
from pygosolnp import solve
from tabulate import tabulate
from time import time

inicial_time = time()


def simulation(n, re, alpha):
    def exp2(o):
        return -sum(log(expon.pdf(v, scale=o)))

    mean = array(["Mean"])
    variance = array(["Variance"])
    bias = array(["Bias"])
    eqm = array(["EQM"])
    skewness = array(["Skewness"])
    kurtose = array(["Kurtose"])
    for i in n:
        param = array([])
        for j in range(re):
            v = random.exponential(alpha, size=i)
            param = append(param, array(solve(exp2, [0], [10]).best_solution.parameters))

        med = param.mean()
        varia = param.var()
        b = Alpha - med
        eqma = b ** 2 + varia
        skewn = skew(param)
        kur = kurtosis(param)

        mean = append(mean, med)
        variance = append(variance, varia)
        bias = append(bias, b)
        eqm = append(eqm, eqma)
        skewness = append(skewness, skewn)
        kurtose = append(kurtose, kur)

    data = [mean, variance, bias, eqm, skewness, kurtose]

    print(tabulate(data, headers=["Statistics", "n = 30", "n = 50", "n = 100", "n = 200", "n = 300"]))
    

N = [30, 50, 100, 200, 300]
RE = 100
Alpha = 1/5

simulation(N, RE, Alpha)

print(f'{time()-inicial_time} seconds')
```

Comment: Why do you calculate `random.exponential(alpha, size=i)` over and over again `re` times?

Comment: You might experiment with creating your rows as Python lists and converting to numpy after, instead of using `numpy.append`.  That's not a quick API.

Comment: @mkrieger1 to make `re` samples of the exponential function to have ´re´ estimated parameters and de mean of this parameters will the same as the E(paramater) because they converge into that number, but to this happen re has to go to infinity or a big value.  @Tim Roberts Thanks for the answer this makes more sense like this.

Comment: use `import numpy as np`, then `np.func_name`. It will be easier for you and everyone else to read your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the helpful comments you got, I think the exponential function is also a function that can take time for the computer to compute. You can use JIT compilation with Numba to make the computation faster. It is a Just-in-Time (JIT) compiler for Python that translates a subset of Python and NumPy code into fast machine code. You can just do this to use it:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def exp2(o):
    return -sum(log(expon.pdf(v, scale=o)))
```

This will save some time when exp2() is called.